# API-Platform : expose an entity only as a subresource

Tags: rest, relationship, api-platform.com

The question is about a PHP 8.0 / symfony 5.3 / API-Platform 2.6 project.

- 2 entities, User and Game.
- User owns games.
- Resources and subresources are well configured, as the 2 examples below are already
  working.

What I try to achieve is to restrict Game to ONLY be exposed as a User's subresource , like this:

```
https://whatever.com/users/{id}/games/{id}
```

And NOT have the generic endpoint anymore, for games, like this:

```
https://whatever.com/games/{id}
```

Do you know how to perform this restriction?

Comment: [The documentation for API Platform version 2.6](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#enabling-and-disabling-operations) suggests disabling the `read` and `output` event listeners, and using the `NotFoundAction` as the endpoint controller in order to "disable" it. The `https://whatever.com/games/{id}` endpoint will still be exposed though, unfortunately.

Comment: @JeroenvanderLaan so this is basically bending the OpenAPI documentation in order to hide those endpoints ? That's a decent workaround, for not critical apps. I'll give it a try, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible with API Platform version 2.7+, which is currently in development (but usable, install the main branch). In this version "subresources” are gone, but new PHP attributes have been introduced allowing to use arbitrary URLs. This basically replace subresources and add write support (POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE) to them.

Comment: That's a wonderful news! I can wait for 2.7 to be out :) Thank you for everything